# Change different pictures on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block where the main picture changes when clicked

```js
$('.img-to-select__item').click(function () {
  $('.img-to-select__item').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.main-image > img').attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('src'));
  $('.custom-carousel__title > span').html($(this).children('img').attr('data-title'));
});
```

```css
.custom-carousel {
  text-align: center;
}
.main-image > img {
  width:50px;
}
.img-to-select > .img-to-select__item > img {
  heigh:30px;
  width: 30px;
}
.img-to-select {
  overflow: hidden; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content:space-around;
}
.img-to-select > .img-to-select__item {
   display: flex; 
   justify-content:space-around;
}

.img-to-select > .img-to-select__item.selected {
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="custom-carousel-section">
  <div class="custom-container">
    <div class="custom-carousel">
      <div class="custom-carousel__title">
        <span>Title
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="main-image">
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" alt="" data-title="image-a">
      </div>
      <div class="img-to-select">
        <div class="img-to-select__item selected">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" alt="" data-title="image-a">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/309/200/300.jpg?hmac=gmsts4-400Ihde9dfkfZtd2pQnbZorV4nBKlLOhbuMs" alt="" data-title="image-b">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/200/300.jpg?hmac=XQWeukbBSi6WSlgZllfOJjG8AQQXS9dYI8IqvKpE1ss" alt="" data-title="image-c">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/494/200/300.jpg?hmac=YdLwRbrTAzFXaAJcsj854mgNuS5jqYM8bcjCzSrSDRM" alt="" data-title="image-d">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now everything works so when you click on `img-to-select` it becomes `main-image`. But can it be done a little differently?

Let's say there are two fields `main_image` and `preview_image`, they will be exactly the same, the only size is different

Suppose we have one `main-test.jpg` picture, it is in the `main-image` class, and exactly the same picture, only with a smaller size `preview-test.jpg` in class `img-to-select`

And there are several such pictures

> main-test-1.jpg and preview-test-1.jpg
> main-test-2.jpg and preview-test-2.jpg
> main-test-3.jpg and preview-test-3.jpg
> main-test-4.jpg and preview-test-4.jpg

The code will now look like this

```
<div class="main-image">
   <img src="main-test-1.jpg" alt="" data-title="image-a">
   //The rest of the pictures are there but will be hidden until we select the desired one
   <img src="main-test-2.jpg" alt="" data-title="image-a">
   <img src="main-test-3.jpg" alt="" data-title="image-a">
   <img src="main-test-4.jpg" alt="" data-title="image-a">

</div>
<div class="img-to-select">
   <div class="img-to-select__item selected">
      <img src="preview-test-1.jpg" alt="" data-title="image-a">
   </div>
   <div class="img-to-select__item">
      <img src="preview-test-2.jpg" alt="" data-title="image-a">
   </div>
   <div class="img-to-select__item">
      <img src="preview-test-3.jpg" alt="" data-title="image-a">
   </div>
   <div class="img-to-select__item">
      <img src="preview-test-4.jpg" alt="" data-title="image-a">
   </div>
```

And now when we click on `preview-test-1.jpg` we display `main-test-1.jpg`, when we click on `preview-test-2.jpg` we display `main-test-2.jpg` and so on

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to how you're handling the `data-title`, you can add another data attribute to the `img` tag that defines its "main" image, while the `src` remains the "preview" image.

```
<img src="https://www.previewimage.com/" data-main-src="https://placekitten.com/201/301">
```

Then in JS, instead of pulling the `src` of the `img`, read the `data-main-src` value and set that as the main `src`:

```
$('.main-image > img').attr('src', $(this).children('img').data('main-src'));
```

```js
$('.img-to-select__item').click(function () {
  $('.img-to-select__item').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.main-image > img').attr('src', $(this).children('img').data('main-src'));
  $('.custom-carousel__title > span').html($(this).children('img').attr('data-title'));
});

// trigger this on page load so the "main" image is displayed instead of the preview.
$('.img-to-select__item.selected').click();
```

```css
.custom-carousel {
  text-align: center;
}
.main-image > img {
  width:50px;
}
.img-to-select > .img-to-select__item > img {
  heigh:30px;
  width: 30px;
}
.img-to-select {
  overflow: hidden; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content:space-around;
}
.img-to-select > .img-to-select__item {
   display: flex; 
   justify-content:space-around;
}

.img-to-select > .img-to-select__item.selected {
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-carousel-section">
  <div class="custom-container">
    <div class="custom-carousel">
      <div class="custom-carousel__title">
        <span>Title
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="main-image">
        <img src="" alt="" data-title="">
      </div>
      <div class="img-to-select">
        <div class="img-to-select__item selected">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/939/200/300.jpg?hmac=cj4OIUh8I6eW-hwT25m1_dCA6ZsAmSYixKCgsbZZmXk" alt="" data-title="image-a" data-main-src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/309/200/300.jpg?hmac=gmsts4-400Ihde9dfkfZtd2pQnbZorV4nBKlLOhbuMs" alt="" data-title="image-b" data-main-src="https://placekitten.com/201/301">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/220/200/300.jpg?hmac=XQWeukbBSi6WSlgZllfOJjG8AQQXS9dYI8IqvKpE1ss" alt="" data-title="image-c" data-main-src="https://placekitten.com/202/302">
        </div>
        <div class="img-to-select__item">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/494/200/300.jpg?hmac=YdLwRbrTAzFXaAJcsj854mgNuS5jqYM8bcjCzSrSDRM" alt="" data-title="image-d" data-main-src="https://placekitten.com/203/303">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: everything works, thanks, you helped me a lot)